# Gap between difference in paragraph size

Tags: css, spacing, paragraph

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BE4sy/

Essentially, I would like to eliminate the gap between these two paragraphs. I realise this is a very inexperienced question, but I can't figure out how.

Here's the code:

html:

```
<p id='big'>
Big Text
</p>
<p id='small'>
Small Text
</p>`
```

css:

```
#big
{
font-size:100px;
}
#small
{
font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: You should mark any of the below as answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give them `margin: 0` , have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/BE4sy/2/

Answer (score 1):

Setting the margin changes the gaps:

```
p { margin:0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `css` with this code

```
#big
{
   font-size:100px;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
#small
{
   font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
#big
{
    font-size:100px;
    line-height:0px;
}
#small
{
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:0px;
}
p { margin:0; }
```

Comment: I tried that, but it shifts the big text up, and the gap remains!